# Azure Cloud Service with SSL on Sub-Domain

Tags: ssl, azure

I have an Azure Cloud Service set up as follows:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web" physicalDirectory="../SampleWebsite/">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="Admin" physicalDirectory="../SampleWebsite/Admin">
    <VirtualApplication name="Admin" physicalDirectory="../SampleWebsite/Admin">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn"/>
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpsIn" protocol="https" port="443" certificate="www.domain.com" />
</Endpoints>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="www.domain.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
</Certificates>
```

I am trying to require SSL for the https://www.domain.com/Admin directory. However, this configuration allows connection to this URL without SSL. Is there a way to require SSL on a sub-directory in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use breischi's answer if you are using MVC and implement the [RequiresSSL] attribute for any controller and/or action you want to force through SSL.  Otherwise, you could also use Url Rewrite to accomplish the task (add rule to web.config):

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
    <match url="^.*/Admin/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/Admin/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If /SampleWebsite/ has all the code for the /Admin/ subdirectory, I don't think there's a way to prevent users from connecting to it with HTTP. I think you have a couple of options here:

1. Enforce HTTPS at the application level. There are a lot of ways to do that, depending on how your application is organized. For instance, if you're using ASP.NET [MVC, here's an option](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/25/requiring-ssl-for-asp-net-mvc-controllers.aspx). You could also roll your own solution using code in the Global.asax handler, or using an HttpModule, or any number of other ways.
2. Split out the /Admin/ subdirectory into its own separate site. Make sure the the site being served on HTTP doesn't have any of the code for the /Admin/ site - then there's no way it can serve that content. Set up a separate site in the .csdef, which you've already pretty much done, to serve the /Admin/ site.